# Memory error: Allocation failure: not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: ssas, olap, cube

I was trying to run the cube script to install the cube-database in the analysis server. I changed the data source to point to the server I wanted, but I got the error as in the title with the error codes

Error Code = 0x8007000E, External Code = 0x00000000:

I tried the properties of the analysis server too and set the "MemoryLimitErrorEnbales" to false. That did not help.

Any insight would be a great help.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

well,

I dont the exact reason why does that happen. But, I found the solution to that problem. I did everthing right like set the "MemoryLimitErrorEnbaled" properties to false. But I forgot to restart the Analysis services.

Also if setting MemoryLimitErrorEnabled  to false does not work, there are other things to look around, like play around with BufferMemoryLimit, aggregationmemorylimitmax,  and then restart the analysis services.